# Importing multiple git repositories into one project in Intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github, intellij-idea

I'm moving over from eclipse to Intellij, and I hit a snag on setting up my project

I have 4 projects on github that, in eclipse, all live in one workspace.  They are API, Server, Client, and Basic Plugin, and they each have a Maven pom.

What I want to do is set up Intellij's project structure similar to Eclipse's workspace, where all 4 of those projects are side by side in the explorer, but it's not letting me import more than one maven project as a module (I import the first fine, but the rest silently fail), and importing directly from github creates a whole new project for each repository, which is not ideal.

I tried to import a in my eclipse workspace, but it all broke (Object and Math were not found), and all the java environment setting were wrong.

Any ideas?  I'm fairly new with Intellij and I really like it, but I don't want to switch over from eclipse if I can't get my workflow right.

Answer (score 17):

First of all, Intellij IDEA uses different naming than Eclipse, you can learn the details here: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html. In short, Eclipse's Workspace is called Project in IDEA, and Eclipse's Project is Module in IDEA. In your case, you want to have multiple Maven-based modules in one Project. You can do it by creating a Project with one Module and then adding the rest of Modules (File->Add Module->Import Module from external model->Maven etc.).

As for the multiple Git repositories, you can configure that using this help page: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/git-branches-in-multirooted-projects.html

In your case, have a look at the 'Asynchronous branch control' section). It's really straightforward, I have just done it myself for the first time by following these instructions.

Good luck.

UPDATE: The above link now gives 404, so here are the most up-to-date ones that may be of help:

1. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/git-branches-in-multirooted-projects.html
2. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html

Comment: Link is now broken: new link I guess is https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/08/git-branches-for-multi-root-projects/

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ opens one project at  time,  but this project can have multiple modules  ( say, maven reactor ).  So modules are kind of [related] workspace projects in eclipse.  You also can open several independent projects in different windows.

In case you have working maven reactor build,  you can just open topmost pom as project and everything will be set up.  ( treat maven reactor as your workspace )